# Hibernate - mapping OneToOne on OrderColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Node entity

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@OrderColumn(name = "POSITION")
private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

Paragraph entity

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "paragraph")
private Node node;
```

When I try to do paragraph.getNode() I always get a null. What I am always missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "@ManyToOne" instead of @OneToOne. Also, the "mappedBy" must be on the @OneToMany, like so:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "node" ...)

Please refer to the JPA 2.0 documentation or the "JavaEE Tutorial" for an explanation.